# DOMPDF: Image not readable or empty. (with barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)

Tags: php, html, image, laravel, dompdf

I'm using DOMPDF along with Laravel-dompdf and after hours of research I cannot find a solution that will enable my images to render.
I've referenced these questions already:

[DomPDF: Image not readable or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558449/dompdf-image-not-readable-or-empty)

[dompdf image not real image not readable or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543796/dompdf-image-not-real-image-not-readable-or-empty)

In both package config files I have `def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", true);` and `def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD", true);`. And of course I have checked the paths, they are all correct. I also tried [this solution](http://www.lost-in-code.com/programming/php-code/dompdf-images-not-working/), which didn't work for me.

Can anyone offer a different solution?

Comment: Where is the image located and how are you referencing it in the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using public path:

`<img src="{{ public_path('image.jpg') }}" />`